# Replacing NA values with mode from multiple imputation in R

Tags: r, replace, mode, imputation

I ran 5 imputations on a data set with missing values. For my purposes, I want to replace missing values with the mode from the 5 imputations. Let's say I have the following data sets, where df is my original data, ID is a grouping variable to identify each case, and imp is my imputed data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                 var1 = c(1,NA,3,6,NA),
                 var2 = c(NA,1,2,6,6),
                 var3 = c(NA,2,NA,4,3))

imp <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5), 
                 var1 = c(1,2,3,3,2,5,4,5,6,6,7,2,3,2,5,6,5,6,6,6,3,1,2,3,2),
                 var2 = c(4,3,2,3,2,4,6,5,4,4,7,2,4,2,3,6,5,6,4,5,3,3,4,3,2),
                 var3 = c(7,6,5,6,6,2,3,2,4,2,5,4,5,3,5,1,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,1))
```

I have a method that works, but it involves a ton of manual coding as I have ~200 variables total (I'm doing this on 3 different data sets with different variables). My code looks like this for one variable:

```
library(dplyr)

mode <- function(codes){
  which.max(tabulate(codes))
}

var1 <- imp %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(var1 = mode(var1))

df3 <- df %>% 
  left_join(var1, by = "ID") %>% 
  mutate(var1 = coalesce(var1.x, var1.y)) %>% 
  select(-var1.x, -var1.y)
```

Thus, the original value in df is replaced with the mode only if the value was NA.

It is taking forever to keep manually coding this for every variable. I'm hoping there is an easier way of calculating the mode from the imputed data set for each variable by ID and then replacing the NAs with that mode in the original data. I thought maybe I could put the variable names in a vector and somehow iterate through them with one code where i changes to each variable name, but I didn't know where to go with that idea.

```
x <- colnames(df)

# Attempting to iterate through variables names using i
i = as.factor(x[[2]])
```

This is where I am stuck. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `df %>% left_join(var1, by = "ID") %>% 
  mutate(var1 = coalesce(var1.x, var1.y))` returns  an error `Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `var1`. ℹ `var1 = coalesce(var1.x, var1.y)`.x Can't combine `..1` <double> and `..2` <character>.` Can you fix it?

Comment: I've run this code a few times and checked that I didn't have other packages loaded that might be interfering, and I am not receiving any errors. I wonder if anyone else is having an issue with this code?

Comment: That is because you do have a function called `mode` that returns a numeric value yet this function is not defined. You need to post the function too. Also, you rather call it `Mode` instead of `mode` since `mode` refers to the data type storage. eg check `?base::mode`.

Comment: @PeaceWang You are calling `mode` function from base R yet OP is calling a user defined function.

Comment: @Onyambu Clear. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you - I completely forget about that line as I've been playing around with the code and it's looking pretty messy...I added the function to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using `tidyverse`. Essentially, we can pivot both dataframes long, then join together and `coalesce` in one step rather than column by column. `Mode` function taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/15293191).

```
library(tidyverse)

Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

imp_long <- imp %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), Mode)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  left_join(imp_long, by = c("ID", "name")) %>%
  mutate(var1 = coalesce(value.x, value.y)) %>%
  select(-c(value.x, value.y)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "var1")
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
     ID  var1  var2  var3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     3     6
2     2     5     1     2
3     3     3     2     5
4     4     6     6     4
5     5     3     6     3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)

mode_data <- imp %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with('var'), Mode))

df %>%
  left_join(mode_data, by = 'ID') %>%
  transmute(ID, 
            across(matches('\\.x$'), 
            function(x) coalesce(x, .[[sub('x$', 'y', cur_column())]]), 
            .names = '{sub(".x$", "", .col)}'))

#  ID var1 var2 var3
#1  1    1    3    6
#2  2    5    1    2
#3  3    3    2    5
#4  4    6    6    4
#5  5    3    6    3
```

- `mode_data` has Mode value for each of the `var` columns.
- Join `df` and `mode_data` by `ID`.
- Since all the pairs have `name.x` and `name.y` in their name, we can take all the `name.x` pairs replace `x` with `y` to get corresponding pair of columns. (`.[[sub('x$', 'y', cur_column())]]`)
- Use `coalesce` to select the non-NA value in each pair.
- Change the column name by removing `.x` from the name. (`{sub(".x$", "", .col)}`) so `var1.x` becomes only `var1`.

where `Mode` function is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/3962914)

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

imp %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), Mode)) %>% 
  bind_rows(df) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ coalesce(last(.x), first(.x))))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>      ID  var1  var2  var3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     3     6
#> 2     2     5     1     2
#> 3     3     3     2     5
#> 4     4     6     6     4
#> 5     5     3     6     3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```